# How to know if a screen is reduced or increased? [real time]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if users **reduced** or **increased** there screens.

I have the following function and it works fine, but it relies only on the **initial screen size**:

```
var width = $(window).width();

$(function(){

    $(window).resize(function(){

      var resizeWidth = $(this).width();

      if (resizeWidth > width) {

        console.log('increased!')
        width = width + 1;

      } else {

        console.log('reduced!')
        width = width - 1;

      }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to know if the screen is **increased** or **reduced** at any time and not on the initial screen size?

**Thank you all!**

Comment: Do you mean zoom? Or height/width?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)

Comment: `screen.height`, `screen.width` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.resize` that you've set up will fire continuously . Simply store the old width each time you resize and compare it to the new width, replacing the old width with the new after the comparison.

```js
var win = $(window); // cache the window query since we'll be using it a lot

// set initial values
var oldWindowWidth = win.width();

// each time we resize
win.on('resize', function() {
  // get the new width
  var newWindowWidth = win.width();

  // compare it to the old width
  if (newWindowWidth > oldWindowWidth) {
    console.log('increased');
  }
  else if (newWindowWidth < oldWindowWidth) {
    console.log('descreased');
  }

  // update the old width
  var oldWindowWidth = newWindowWidth;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `oldWindowWidth = newWindowWidth;`. Ho, so obvious now...Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to check increase and decrease your window width

```js
var windowWidth = 0;

$(window).ready(function () {
  windowWidth = $(window).width();
})

$(window).resize(function () {
  var newWindowWidth = $(window).width();
  if (windowWidth >= newWindowWidth) {
    console.log('Decrease width');
  } else {
    console.log('Increase width');
  }
  
  windowWidth = newWindowWidth;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```